# using special character in OS X terminal script

Tags: linux, bash, macos, terminal

I'm trying to run sudo with command with provided user password in one line

```
echo abc$*@def | sudo -S -u user_account ./script_name
echo abc\$*@def | sudo -S -u user_account ./script_name
echo 'abc$*@def' | sudo -S -u user_account ./script_name
echo 'abc\$*@def' | sudo -S -u user_account ./script_name
```

all of these commands keep getting wrong password please try again error

I also tried changing user password to 'm' and it worked

```
echo 'm' | sudo -S -u user_account ./script_name
```

so that means something is wrong with special char in password

note: I'm using OS X 10.13.3, this is a command run by me only, and I want a one-click solution so I don't have to enter pwd on many machines. and yes security for this pwd is not a concern here

im open to other one-click method too if it's done through scripting

can anyone please help?

Comment: The third one should work if your password really is `abc$*@def`, in my opinion.

Comment: That's a terrible solution to the problem of running the script as another user. It would be much better to configure `sudo` to allow running this script as that user without requiring a password. `man sudoers` seems to have been written for machines, not humans, but e.g. [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159007/how-do-i-run-specific-sudo-commands-without-a-password) has some good advice.

Comment: Why is the password being collected before `sudo` runs?

Comment: @BenjaminW. I thought so too, but 3rd one does not work either

Comment: @chepner thats how to channel pwd to the command, isn't it?

Comment: No; either run `sudo -u user_account ./script_name`, and let the relevant user type their password when prompted, or configure `sudo` to run the command without a password.

Comment: @Thomas yes I understand this is not a good solution, but I have to do this way for some reason

Comment: @chepner, no other users to interact, this is a script run by me only and I'd like a one click solution instead of entering pwd multiple times on a few machines

Answer (score 0):

You could use [heredoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document), give a try to:

```
sudo -S <<< "password from stdin" -u user_account ./script_name
```